# What database structure to use to store varying cost data

Tags: database, database-design, relational-database

I'm looking to set up a database to store information on project costs. These costs can be any cost relating to a project and most of the projects are procurement or manufacture projects. For example, the costs of a new aeroplane. This could be the cost of an entire communications system or the individual cost of bolts or steel. It could also be the labour cost of fitters per hour.

The database will then be queried if a future related project is started. For example if the project is the building of a new hospital then the database could be queried for costs related to building materials or costs of similar medical facilities.

To do this using a normal relational database I would try and group similar  costs into tables and generate useful categories and then add data to those tables accordingly. So there would be a building costs table and this would have various categories relating to building costs.

What I want though is as much flexibility on what data and categories can go into the database with as much power in the resultant queries as possible. Is there a better way to do this than a standard relational database?

Thanks for your help.

Comment: You should ask your question on [DBA stackexchange](https://dba.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic), you have better chance to solve your problem.

Comment: Thanks, didn't know it existed. I'll post it there as well.

Comment: You can use the same account, you have just to use "Join this community".